# Calling JSF ManageBean after PageLoad using f:event postAddToView

Tags: java, javascript, http, jsf-2

I am writing an app using JSF 2.0.

For one of the page, there is a section of the page that takes a long time to display.

To improve the  user experience, I am thinking to load the page first and then automatically do an Ajax call back to the JSF manage bean object once the page is loaded successfully after 1st load.

I am thinking to use f:event with type postAddView.

```
<h:outputText id="dummyId">
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{mngBean.doSomething}" />
</h:outputText>
```

However it seems like **f:event postAddToView** is still being processed before the page is displayed for the first time.

The other options that I have explore is to create a hidden button and get javascript to trigger it. It works however I am just wondering if there is a nice JSF component/event that can do this instead of using java script.

Thanks for your help.

```
<h:commandButton id="dmyButton"
```

value="#{mngBean.getSomething}" 
 actionListener="#{mngBean.doSomething}" 
 style="display: none" 
 type="submit">

Java Script

```
<script language="JavaScript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  if (document.getElementById('form:dmyButton').value == 'true') {
   document.getElementById('form:dmyButton').click();
  }

 });
</script>
```

Thanks for all your help in advance

Comment: Very good question. Would like to see a component for this (javascript firing an event after the page is loaded) in Primefaces... I think it does not exist at the moment. I'm going to link your question in the support forum.

Answer (score 4):

I think the PreRenderViewEvent is what you want.

http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/event/PreRenderViewEvent.html

Though the docs don't show it, the preRenderViewEvent does work with f:event.  I'll fix the docs presently.

Comment: As pointed out on irc.freenode.net ##jsf, they want to update the page after the first show.  In this case, I recommend creating a custom component that you can wrap around the portions of your page that you want lazily updated.  This is really a job for the client behavior renderer.

Answer (score 0):

PostAddToViewEvent is processed "During Restore View Phase, after a
component has been added to a view." (according to *Java Server Faces 2.0 - The Complete Reference*) which means it is really early in the lifecycle (Restore View is the first lifecycle phase).

I don't think that any PhaseListener will help you in this case, since they all run on the server side, not on the client side.

However, `<f:ajax>` can be applied to `<h:body>`, with `event="load"`. I tried it, but it didn't really work, `<f:ajax>` wrapping `<h:body>` nothing happened, the other way around I got `Unable to attach <f:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent` error.